# Inno setup pass command line argument into #define

Tags: installation, arguments

I want to pass an argument into Inno setup and ultimately create a string which has this argument (which happens to be the year) in the middle of some text e.g. if I pass MyYear=2018 to the Inno setup command line I want to make

AppName=Some text 2018 some more text

I tried to do

```
#define MyAppName="Some text" {#MyYear} "some more text"
```

and also

```
#define AppName1 "Some text"
#define AppName2 "some more text"
#define MyAppName={#AppName1} {#MyYear} {#AppName2}
```

then in setup

```
AppName={#MyAppName}
```

but it didn't like me passing the argument into the #define part - is this not allowed?

I have ended up with something that feels rather clumsy (but works) namely creating 2 strings which are either side of the argument i want to pass in and then appending the 3 strings together...

```
#define AppName1 "Some text"
#define AppName2 "some more text"
```

then in setup

```
AppName={#AppName1} {#MyYear} {#AppName2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

`#define MyAppName AppName1 + ' ' + MyYear + ' ' + AppName2`